# Standard deviation / Bell Shaped Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation

In a forest, it is known that the circumference of 10 year old oak trees when measured three feet above the ground is 20 inches with a standard deviation of 4.5 inches. It is also known that these circumferences follow a bell-shaped distribution. If a random sample of 200 ten year old oak trees is selected, approximately how many would have girths greater than 29 inches?

Comment: May I humbly ask:what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Have you tried using the 68/95/99.7 rule? 9 inches greater than the mean is 2 standard deviations.

The question is asking for the area to the right of $2 \sigma$. Since the interval within $2\sigma$ from the mean is 95%, the left and right combined is 5%, so the area only to the right is 2.5%.

Comment: I know what the rule says but do not really understand it or how to use it...I am taking the course online, so I am trying to teach myself...

Comment: Ok...so is it just asking me to find 95% of 200?

Comment: @user129854 I've edited my answer